# How can I troubleshoot PCs not seeing each other over my LAN

Tags: django, file-transfer, lan

1. I'm a complete newbie when it comes to networking. I have two PCs on my LAN both running Manjaro. My main aim is to test functionality on a Django server running on one PC, from the other. I am running the Django server on the PC with ip address 192.168.1.138 using the command

   python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.138:8000

and in **settings.py**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost',  '192.168.1.138']
```

I can ping 192.168.1.138 from the client PC, and ping the client PC from the server PC. But if I enter the ip address/port into the browser, it fails with

> took too long to respond

2. I don't know if this a separate problem or a manifestation of the first, but when I run *NitroShare*, I am able to 'see' the PC running the Django server from the PC acting as the client, but if I try to transfer a file, again it times out. I am unable to see the client from the server in NitroShare.

Any suggestions or help gratefully received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure you don't have a firewall running (or that it allows connections to port 8000). Manjaro's docs imply there might be no firewall by default, but in case there is, see https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Firewalls
2. Set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`, don't bother with limiting them.
3. Run with `python manage.py runserver 0:8000` ; the `0` stands for `0.0.0.0`, i.e. has the server listening on all network interfaces.

Comment: Thank you. It was the firewall. I had installed UFV. With turned off it works. I'll look at the settings now. So, does the firewall allow pinging?

Comment: Pinging is ICMP; the firewall probably only blocks TCP and UDP.

Answer (score 0):

First I would scan with the other PC the open ports of you "Server"-PC, you can do that with tools like Nmap. Make sure you opened the ports of your "Server"-PC at your router interface. Another option could be the launching of the django app in a docker container. Here's the link of the official docker image at DockerHub:
https://hub.docker.com/_/django